# Can't I simply copy and paste a program from a Jupyter notebook to a file.py?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

It's weird, I wrote a functioning program on a Jupyter notebook and I wanted to have it in a normal python file with VSCode aswell. However, while copying and pasting the exact same code that doesn't give me any troubles in Jupyter, I get the message from VSCode:

```
module 'keras.engine.base_layer' has no attribute 'BaseRandomLayer'
```

In the line

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I am, of course, in the same environment (anaconda with python 3.9.7)
Tensorflow version: 2.8.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the multiple versions of `Tensorflow` or mismatching version of `Tensorflow` with `Keras` or other dependencies.

You can create a new environment and install latest tensorflow using.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.9.0
```

You can import all the packages using Tensorflow using below lines.

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
```